# Deploying .NET to Heroku - build fails to create xproj.metaproj project file

Tags: visual-studio, heroku, mono, asp.net-core

The main page on the heroku website links to a non existent github page, hence I cannot use it.
https://elements.heroku.com/buttons/herokumx/herokumxnet
https://github.com/herokumx/herokumxnet

I did find lots of SO posts linking to this build pack and sample application.
https://github.com/jincod/dotnetcore-buildpack
https://github.com/jincod/AspNet5DemoApp

I tried deploying a completely unmodified version of the above application (you can repeat it yourself) but the build process fails with no specific errors. Here is the deployment log.

It complains it can't find xproj.metaproj which from what I have read is a dynamcially created metaproject. Typically used on build servers. So I'm assuming the build process is failing at some point, but I have no idea where or how. Is there anything I can add to the build pack to get more specific build errors?

I've tried a few times with fresh clones/using their built in template system however I always the same build error.

Is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

```
...
remote: APT packages Installled 
remote: Installing dotnet 
remote: 
remote: Welcome to .NET Core! 
remote: --------------------- 
remote: Learn more about .NET Core @ https://aka.ms/dotnet-docs. Use dotnet
--he lp to see available commands or go to https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-docs. 
remote: 
remote: Telemetry 
remote:-------------- 
remote: The .NET Core tools collect usage data in order to improve your experien ce. The data is anonymous and does not include commandline arguments. The data i s collected by Microsoft and shared with the community. remote: You can opt out of telemetry by setting a DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT en vironment variable to 1 using your favorite shell. remote: You can read more about .NET Core tools telemetry @ https://aka.ms/dotne t-cli-telemetry. 
remote: 
remote: Configuring... 
remote: ------------------- 
remote: A command is running to initially populate your local package cache, to improve restore speed and enable offline access. This command will take up to a minute to complete and will only happen once. remote: Decompressing 100% 2659 ms 
remote: Expanding 100% 8029 ms 
remote: /tmp/build_bb0646bd8303182f6bd73ce264103dff/dotnet/sdk/1.0.0-preview5-00 4232/NuGet.targets(164,5): 
error MSB3202: The project file "/tmp/build_bb0646bd8 303182f6bd73ce264103dff/src/AspNet5DemoApp/AspNet5DemoApp.xproj.metaproj" was not found. [/tmp/build_bb0646bd8303182f6bd73ce264103dff/AspNet5DemoApp.sln] 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile ASP.NET Core app. 
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed 
remote: Verifying deploy... 
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to ****. 
remote:

Warning: Your console font probably doesn't support Unicode. If you experience strange characters in the output, consider switching to a TrueType font such as Consolas! To https://git.heroku.com/****.git  ! 
[remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/****.git'
```

Edit: I tried this build pack as well with the same no error failure
http://github.com/heroku/dotnet-buildpack.git

```
remote: installing https://github.com/friism/mono-builder/releases/download/v4.0
.1.44/mono-4.0.1.44.tar.gz
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile ASP.NET 5 app.
```

edit2: Tried replicating the build script on windows using the same project file etc and it all compiles fine.

```
dotnet publish project.json --output pathtoproject\heroku-output\ --configuration Release
Publishing AspNet5DemoApp for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
Project AspNet5DemoApp (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because expected outputs are missing
Compiling AspNet5DemoApp for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0

Compilation succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time elapsed 00:00:02.4511992

publish: Published to ...\heroku-output\
Published 1/1 projects successfully
```

Edit3: I edited the build pack to add  - - verbose but no change in the output. Is there some kind of stream I need to feed the output to so I can read any possible errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I used noliar's buildpack to successfully get a minimal .net core
>   application up and running.
>
> Steps:
>
> 1: Find the folder that you house your git repos in.
>
> 2: RightClick-->Git Bash Here on that folder.
>
> 3: Heroku create my-app-name --buildpack
>   https://github.com/noliar/dotnet-buildpack.git
>
> 4: The response should give you the git url, clone it:

```
$ git clone https://git.heroku.com/my-app-name.git
```

> 5: Copy and Paste project.json and Program.cs into root of my-app-name
>   folder. Contents of project.json:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*"
    ,
    "buildOptions": 
    {
        "debugType": "portable"
        ,
        "emitEntryPoint": true
    }
    ,
    "dependencies": {}
    ,
    "frameworks": 
    {
        "netcoreapp1.0": 
        {
            "dependencies": 
            {
                "Microsoft.NETCore.App": 
                {
                  "type": "platform",
                  "version": "1.0.0"
                }
                ,
                "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel":"1.0.0"
            }
            ,
            "imports": "dnxcore50"
        }
    }
}
```

> Contents Of Program.cs: Based on minimal asp.net core app tutorial
>   here: http://ardalis.com/the-minimal-aspnet-core-app  With additions
>   to get the app to bind the the correct port.

```
//using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environmentvariabletarget(v=vs.110).aspx
// This example demonstrates the 
//     Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable,
//     Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable, and 
//     Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables overloaded methods.
using System;
using System.Collections;
using Microsoft.Win32;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

using System.Linq;  //<--to get string[].First extention 

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    ///<summary>
    ///This class stores the url that the heroku app will launch on.
    ///It also stores a debug message variable that we can print out
    ///to the application.
    ///</summary>
    public class UrlData
    {
        /// <summary> The url in format such as "http://localhost:5000" 
        /// that the application will attach to. </summary>
        public string url = null;

        /// <summary> A debug message that will give us some insight into what happened 
        /// in the function that produced the .url component of the UrlData. </summary>
        public string debug_message = "[DEBUG_MSG_NOT_SET]";
    }

    public class Program
    {

        public static UrlData 
        GetUrl(string[] args)
        {
             //inn=="arguments inputs by priority"
            string[] inn = new string[3]; //3 elements.

            //inn[0] = "[NOTHING_FOUND]";
            inn[0] = String.Join(" | ", args);

            //NOTE: Using "$PORT" and "PORT" both will cause crash on heroku:
            inn[1] = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("$PORT"); //with "$"
            //inn[2] = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT"); //NO "$"


            //Get first non-null and non-empty entry in array:
            String dyna_port = null;
            if(true == String.IsNullOrEmpty( inn[0] )){
                //Simple processing:
                dyna_port = inn.FirstOrDefault( s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) );
            }else{
                //Parse the command line args:
                //Which will look like:
                // --server.urls | 5001 | 5002 | 5003
                string[] port_args = inn[0].Split('|');
                string port_arg_name = port_args[0];
                dyna_port = port_args[1];
            }


            String port_num = (String.IsNullOrEmpty( dyna_port )) ?
                              "4998" : dyna_port;

            String use_url = "[NOT_SET_USE_URL]";
            if(port_num.Contains("http") ){
                //The command-line likely injected an argument like:
                //"http://5000:80" for the port to use.
                use_url = port_num;
            }else{
                //The command-line likely injected an argument like:
                //"5000" for the server.urls.
                //Interpret it as "Port #5000"
                use_url = "http://localhost:" + port_num;
            }

            //res_msg == "response message"
            String nl = "\n";
            String res_msg = "[Working From Port#]:" + port_num + nl +
                             "|inn[0]=="             + inn[0]   + nl +
                             "|inn[1]=="             + inn[1]   + nl +
                             "|inn[2]=="             + inn[2]   ;

            UrlData results = new UrlData();
            results.url = use_url;
            results.debug_message = res_msg;

            return results;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Step#1: Get Url to operate on:
            UrlData ud = GetUrl( args ); //ud=="url + debug-message"

            //Uncondensed Version, so you can see what classes are being
            //Used where in the chaining:
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder  w1;
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostBuilder w2;
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostBuilder w2_5; //2_5 == 2.5
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostBuilder w3;
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHost        w4;  

            w1 = new WebHostBuilder();
            w2 = w1.UseKestrel();
            w2_5 = w2.UseUrls( ud.url );

            w3 = w2_5.Configure(
                a => a.Run(c => c.Response.WriteAsync(ud.debug_message))
            );

            w4 = w3.Build();
            w4.Run();

            Console.WriteLine("[HELLO_WORLD]");
        }
    }
}
```

> Note: A lot of this code is very messy and experimental. But it will
>   build. And having something to work with is always nice.
>
> Step 6:
>
> On git bash:

```
$ git add .

$ git commit

$ dotnet restore

$> dotnet run
```

> NOTE: If you don't have the .NET CLI installed for your command line,
>   you will need it. It's vital to make sure your applications are
>   properly compiling before you try and push them up. It simplifies
>   troubleshooting.
>
> Step 7: The app should now be running on
>           localhost:4998, if you did not configure a PORT
>           environment variable on your local machine.
>
> Step 8: If it runs, go ahead and do a git push and
>           the project should be successfully deployed.
>        More tips:
>    1. Heroku logs - helped me figure out what was going wrong.
>
> 2. Read the buildpack source code and look for where $PORT is
>      referenced.
> 3. Looks like .net application cannot access the $PORT environment variable
>      when running on heroku, so the port needs to be injected via a command
>      line argument. Which the noliar buildpack is setup to do.
> 4. This guy's post helped me understand some of the build script I was using. Especially the line:

```
dotnet run --server.urls http://+:8080
```

> Article here:

```
https://blog.jenyay.com/running-asp-net-core-in-heroku/
```

> Hopefully this helped. It took me a lot of research to figure this
>   out. Was actually hoping that I would be able to come back to your
>   post to find it answered by someone else.
>
> Also, sorry about the indentation on the C# code. I had to blast it
>   all away to get the submission through.

Comment: I actually moved back to azure as I didn't have time to continue trailing it out. I would try this out but unfortunately don't have the time. I'll accept your answer though as its very detailed! Thanks

Comment: I feel you. I almost broke down and got an azure account. But I wanted something I could make a free portfolio on that didn't require money to maintain.